# Beautiful Soup doesn't extract the number of the website, just the formula

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this [website](https://www.temporadalivre.com/aluguel-temporada/brasil/sao-paulo/ubatuba/lagoinha/76203-vila-praiana-apartamento-de-um-quarto-na-praia-da-lagoinha) , I want to extract the value 170 of this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="right">
   <span class="currency">
      R$
   </span>
   <span class="price">
      170
   </span>
   <span class="diary">
      a diária
   </span>
</div>
```

However, when I extract this piece of HTML with beautiful soup, I get:

```
<div class="right">
   <span class="currency">
      R$
   </span>
   <span class="price">
      {{ property.minRateInCents / 100 | numberFormat(0) }}
   </span>
   <span class="diary">
      a diária
   </span>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
soup.find("div", class_="coluna").find("div", class_="right")
```

Why can't I access the value 170 ? What is that formula ?

Comment: You have to show us your code. How are you using beautifulsoup here?

Comment: if possible can you share the URL

Comment: I put my code and I shared the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the `soup` you can find data is present inside `div` tag and you can extract from it

```
import requests
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.temporadalivre.com/aluguel-temporada/brasil/sao-paulo/ubatuba/lagoinha/76203-vila-praiana-apartamento-de-um-quarto-na-praia-da-lagoinha",headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

price=soup.find("div",attrs={"data-behavior":"property-details-data"})['data-property-min-rate-in-cents']
price=int(price)/100
price
```

**Output:**

```
170.0
```

**How to find from site:**

1. Go to Chrome Developer mode and refresh your site and now go to
   Network tab left side you will get a tab to search any data as from
   code we can see it is divided by 100 so use 17000 to search in that
   tab
2. Now it will return URL's you can use that URL and make a call to
   that and find proper tag which has that data

**Image :**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! It worked!. Can you explain why did you do all these steps?

Comment: if you print `soup` and manually search for data you will able to find it but lets say if data is redirected from another URL so that why i put that image and step to give you idea that you can use that also to verify data where it is present!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be some sort of Angular application, which means that the value is rendered on the client side. BeautifulSoup probably retreives the html from the server, which includes the angular javascript *without it being executed* (since that is done at the client).

You could use a headless browser to load the data for you and scrape the values from there.